# Rails 4 - Production assets:precompile results in ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL: database does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, precompile

Can't seem to figure out why I can no longer precompile assets before pushing to Heroku.  Details below.  Currently running Rails 4.1.6. Some other possibly relevant info:

Bundler version 1.7.12.
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
gem 'formtastic', '3.1.2'

All I can find are references to pre-Rails 4 when config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false would fix it, which no longer applies.

Any ideas why it's trying to connect to the database?

```
> RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile

rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  database "xyz" does not exist
Run `$ bin/rake db:create db:migrate` to create your database
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:898:in `rescue in connect'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `connect'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:568:in `initialize'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:435:in `new_connection'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:445:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:416:in `acquire_connection'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:351:in `block in checkout'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:350:in `checkout'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:541:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:214:in `columns'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:223:in `columns_hash'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:48:in `columns_hash'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:170:in `block in pluck'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:169:in `map'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:169:in `pluck'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/querying.rb:14:in `pluck'
/Users/abc/workspace/xyz/app/admin/product.rb:31:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f51d96dddb5e/lib/active_admin/dsl.rb:15:in `instance_exec'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f51d96dddb5e/lib/active_admin/dsl.rb:15:in `run_registration_block'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f51d96dddb5e/lib/active_admin/namespace.rb:223:in `parse_registration_block'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f51d96dddb5e/lib/active_admin/namespace.rb:48:in `register'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f51d96dddb5e/lib/active_admin/application.rb:136:in `register'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f51d96dddb5e/lib/active_admin.rb:75:in `register'
/Users/abc/workspace/xyz/app/admin/product.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f51d96dddb5e/lib/active_admin/application.rb:194:in `block in load'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f51d96dddb5e/lib/active_admin/error.rb:40:in `capture'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f51d96dddb5e/lib/active_admin/application.rb:194:in `load'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f51d96dddb5e/lib/active_admin/application.rb:186:in `block in load!'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f51d96dddb5e/lib/active_admin/application.rb:186:in `each'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f51d96dddb5e/lib/active_admin/application.rb:186:in `load!'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f51d96dddb5e/lib/active_admin/application.rb:208:in `routes'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f51d96dddb5e/lib/active_admin.rb:79:in `routes'
/Users/abc/workspace/xyz/config/routes.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:337:in `instance_exec'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:337:in `eval_block'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:315:in `draw'
/Users/abc/workspace/xyz/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:71:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
/Users/abc/workspace/xyz/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:276:in `require_environment!'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:389:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
PG::Error: FATAL:  database "xyz" does not exist
Run `$ bin/rake db:create db:migrate` to create your database
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `initialize'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `new'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `connect'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:568:in `initialize'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:435:in `new_connection'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:445:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:416:in `acquire_connection'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:351:in `block in checkout'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:350:in `checkout'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:541:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:214:in `columns'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:223:in `columns_hash'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:48:in `columns_hash'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:170:in `block in pluck'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:169:in `map'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:169:in `pluck'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/querying.rb:14:in `pluck'
/Users/abc/workspace/xyz/app/admin/product.rb:31:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f51d96dddb5e/lib/active_admin/dsl.rb:15:in `instance_exec'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f51d96dddb5e/lib/active_admin/dsl.rb:15:in `run_registration_block'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f51d96dddb5e/lib/active_admin/namespace.rb:223:in `parse_registration_block'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f51d96dddb5e/lib/active_admin/namespace.rb:48:in `register'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f51d96dddb5e/lib/active_admin/application.rb:136:in `register'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f51d96dddb5e/lib/active_admin.rb:75:in `register'
/Users/abc/workspace/xyz/app/admin/product.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f51d96dddb5e/lib/active_admin/application.rb:194:in `block in load'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f51d96dddb5e/lib/active_admin/error.rb:40:in `capture'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f51d96dddb5e/lib/active_admin/application.rb:194:in `load'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f51d96dddb5e/lib/active_admin/application.rb:186:in `block in load!'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f51d96dddb5e/lib/active_admin/application.rb:186:in `each'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f51d96dddb5e/lib/active_admin/application.rb:186:in `load!'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f51d96dddb5e/lib/active_admin/application.rb:208:in `routes'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f51d96dddb5e/lib/active_admin.rb:79:in `routes'
/Users/abc/workspace/xyz/config/routes.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:337:in `instance_exec'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:337:in `eval_block'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:315:in `draw'
/Users/abc/workspace/xyz/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:71:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
/Users/abc/workspace/xyz/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:276:in `require_environment!'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:389:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: It looks like you have a reference to `app/admin/product.rb` somewhere in your assets, but the database is not yet created. Did you already run `rake db:create db:migrate` on production?

Comment: I have deployed previously to Heroku, so yes I have a production database.  But I'm doing this precompile locally, so this shouldn't apply?

Comment: I don't believe I purposefully referenced that file in assets, thoughts on how to track that down?  This file isn't new (just significantly changed), since I last tried to deploy (and precompiling was working).

Comment: If you are compiling assets for production on your development machine and in that process it is hitting the database, then it expects a database to be available as configured under `production`. Does that production db exists on your development machine? If so, is it filled with the required seed data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I was too focused on the final lines of the error and trying everything I've read on pages referencing similar text (along with different results between multiple Heroku environments throwing me off more) and skipped over the relevant product.rb lines that would have pointed me to the problem.  I have database references in setting up the scopes and filters for that particular page, didn't realize those would factor into the generation of assets.

```
Product.pluck(:type).uniq.sort.each do |p|
  scope(p) { |scope| scope.where(type: p) }
end

filter :type, as: :select, collection: Product.pluck(:type).uniq.sort
```

After commenting those lines out, precompilation once again works fine.

=====

Once I knew what to search for, found this: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/2781

So better solution was to add this to routes.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.routes(self) unless ARGV.grep(/assets:(precompile|clean)/).any?
```